# Error while estimating a production function with prodest package in R

Tags: production-function, productivity

I have an unbalanced panel with 15063 firms between 2012 and 2018.

I am using this code to estimate the production function with Levinsohn & Petrin method:

```
levpet <- prodestLP(Y=base$c_y,
 fX=base$c_l,
 sX=base$c_k,
 pX=base$c_m,
 idvar=base$ruc,
 timevar = base$year,
 R=100  )
```

where

- `c_y` is log of value added
- `c_l` is log of wages
- `c_k` is log of capital
- `c_m` is log of materials
- `ruc` is the firm identifier (a string)
- `year` is a numeric.

The error I am getting looks like this:

```
Error in `[[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, i, value = c(42719L, 82109L, 82678L,  : 
  replacement has 469326 rows, data has 78221
```

I don´t know what it means or what I have to do about it.

How can I solve it? My data is very similar to this one:

```
data(chilean)
```

data and `prodestLP`function are inside `library(prodest)`

---

These are all the libraries I have in the current script

```
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
library(foreign)
library(haven)
library(readxl)
library(stringr)
library(expss)
library(lubridate)
library(prodest)
library(plm)
```

Thanks in advance.

---

Edit: With the dataset that's in the prodest package it runs just fine. Here's an example: https://rpubs.com/hacamvan/319728

My dataset is very similar, just way more observations, and a string idvar.

---

I think I've made it.

I had to assign a numerical id for every firm. then it worked.

now I just hope I can export the regressions.

Comment: Can you post your own solution as an answer and accept it and then question can be closed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I figured out that the error meant something about not fitting in the dataset. My dataset had 78221 obs.

Everything was like `data(chilean)` the only difference had to be the id for each firm.

So I did this:

```
list <- data.frame(table(base$ruc)) # so here i got the string id for every firm
list$idvar <- seq(1:nrow(list)) # here i put a number for each firm from 1.
list <- select(list, ruc, idvar) # We don't need freq var

base <- base %>% left_join(y=list, by=c("ruc"="ruc")) #join it to the original dataset
```

And then it worked using `base$idvar` instead of using `base$ruc`.

Comment: thank you, this is really helping. I believe the issue was the IDs not being an ordered number starting from 1, which is really annoying

Answer (score 0):

Elaborating on the answer by @Jor Jorge Paredes, it is worth noting that the `idvar` needs to follow the original ID variable, while the above answer does not guarantee that this is the case and may create a wrong numbering.

A safer solution (edited):

```
idlist <- df[, c("time","original_id")] # id for every firm
idlist  <- transform(idlist, idvar = as.numeric(factor(original_id)))
df <- merge(df, idlist, by=c("original_id", "time"), all.x = T) #join it to the original dataset
```

EDIT: Or even smoother

```
 df <- df %>%
   mutate(idvar = as.numeric(factor(original_id)))
```